# Is there any implementation of hstack in gnumpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to transfer python codes in CPU to GPU, but I failed to find the *numpy* function **hstack** in *gnumpy*. Who can give me some hints to implement adding some extra rows to a existing matrix(garray) like hstack in numpy. Thank you.

Comment: `hstack` is a thin wrapper around `concatenate`.  Check its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gnumpy.concatenate`. For 1D arrays you need to reshape to 2D first.